# how to assign the "Enter key" to an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

here i have number input bar with a tag assigned as button , i have an onclick function . how can i make the oncklick to be executed when the user press enter ?  ( at this point the user will input a number in the box and press the button with the mouse - how can i make it so the user will input the number and press Enter and the same onclick function will be executed ? )

many thanks in advance.

i tried some codes but they wont work

```
enter code here


<div id="foot1">

 <form action="" method="" name="vform">
 <input type ="number" min="0" max="10000000" 
  placeholder="PEEM it!" value="" id="footbar"  />
  <div id="foot2">
   <li class="foot" alt="foot"  title="FOOT (ft)" onclick="runfoot()"><a  
  href=""></a></li>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keydown` event or similar (keyup, keypress):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  const ENTERKEY = 13;
  if (event.keyCode === ENTERKEY) {
    runfoot()
  }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery's `click`:

```
$(document).on("keydown", e => {
    if (e.key == "Enter") {
        $(".foot").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```html
<div id="foot1">
      <form action="" method="" name="vform" onsubmit="return false">
        <input
          type="number"
          min="0"
          max="10000000"
          placeholder="PEEM it!"
          value=""
          id="footbar"
        />
        <div id="foot2">
          <li class="foot" alt="foot" title="FOOT (ft)" onclick="runfoot()">
            <a href=""></a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      document
        .getElementById('footbar')
        .addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
          const key = 13;
          if (event.keyCode == key) {
            runfoot();
          }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: thank you so much ! your answer was the best as it was very easy to understand !!! thank you for having the time to answer me !! cheers!

Comment: you're welcome, can you mark my resolution as the one that helped you?